# How do I create a row of SD values for specific columns of a data frame?

Tags: r, standard-deviation

I have a 160 by 250,000 data frame. I want to find the SD of all columns except the first (249,999 columns) in R. Is it possible to do this and add a row of the SD values? These are probe beta-values for DNA methylation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `mtcars`:

```r
mt <- mtcars[1:5,]
rbind(mt, "Standard Deviation" = c(NA, sapply(mt[,-1], sd)))
#                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt qsec   vs   am gear carb
# Mazda RX4           21 6.0  160 110 3.90 2.62 16.5 0.00 1.00 4.00  4.0
# Mazda RX4 Wag       21 6.0  160 110 3.90 2.88 17.0 0.00 1.00 4.00  4.0
# Datsun 710          23 4.0  108  93 3.85 2.32 18.6 1.00 1.00 4.00  1.0
# Hornet 4 Drive      21 6.0  258 110 3.08 3.21 19.4 1.00 0.00 3.00  1.0
# Hornet Sportabout   19 8.0  360 175 3.15 3.44 17.0 0.00 0.00 3.00  2.0
# Standard Deviation  NA 1.4  100  32 0.42 0.45  1.3 0.55 0.55 0.55  1.5
```

Explanation:

- `sapply(mt[,-1], sd)` execute the `sd` function on each column except the first `mt[,-1]`. Because this is `sapply` and the return values are all the same "shape" and class, this returns a vector.
- `c(NA, ..)` is because we don't have a standard-dev for the first column, but since we are row-binding it we need the length to be the same as the number of columns in `mt`.
- `rbind(mt, ..)` is row-binding aka row-concatenation. Because in this case `mtcars` uses row-names to identify, I named the stddev as `"Standard Deviation"`. This may not be necessary or appropriate with your data.

Comment: How would I sort the columns by the SD row (ascending left to right)?

Comment: (1) The premise of sorting *across a row* is mostly counter to the premise of `data.frame`, where a column is a specific field and a row is an observation. But there could be some utility. However ... (2) that is a new question that has nothing to do with this current question/answer. I suggest you create a new question, but *please*: **include sample data**. I offered this answer *from scratch* as a courtesy, but you may find many are unwilling to put in more effort than you demonstrated here (i.e., _very little_). You can even use `mtcars` as that sample, but you really need to show effort.